# How do I return not only the proper data type but an array as well?

Tags: java, return-value, return-type

I am currently drawing a blank on how to return more than what is "commanded"

public static long extendedEuclidGCD(long a, long b, long [] xy)

the code works fine but I am asked to also retrieve the array xy (only size 2) and add the elements their to the output without changing the header. So my question is this, how do I not only return the gcd the method provides, but return the elements inside the array.

Comment: If I understand you (not certain, since your question is a bit confusing), just set `xy[0]=something` or `xy[1]=something` in your method.  An array is an object, and `xy` is a reference to an array, so if you set the elements of that array then the caller will see the new values afterwards.

Comment: P.S. Passing in an array like this to hold output values is IMO poor practice because it makes code hard to read.  It's done sometimes--the Android API does it--but it's hacky.  Best is to define a new simple class that holds all the values you want the method to return.  It's more typing, but a lot cleaner code, I think.  (I know, this wasn't your choice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am asked to also retrieve the array xy**

You are passing an array to the method. In java *references to objects are passed by value*. As long as you modify `xy` **without reassigning it** your modifications will be visible to the *calling* method. So, you don't have to *return the array*.

If you *reassign* the reference `xy` to some other array instance, then you will have to *return* the reference.

Comment: Oh god I forgot about that completely